# Using node http-proxy to proxy websocket connections

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, node-http-proxy

I have an application that uses websockets via socket.io. For my application I would like to use a separate HTTP server for serving the static content and JavaScript for my application. Therefore, I need to put a proxy in place.

I am using [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy). As a starting point I have my websockets app running on port 8081. I am using the following code to re-direct socket.io communications to this standalone server, while using express to serve the static content:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    express = require('express');

// create a server
var app = express();
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({ ws: true });

// proxy HTTP GET / POST
app.get('/socket.io/*', function(req, res) {
  console.log("proxying GET request", req.url);
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8081'});
});
app.post('/socket.io/*', function(req, res) {
  console.log("proxying POST request", req.url);
  proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:8081'});
});

// Proxy websockets
app.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  console.log("proxying upgrade request", req.url);
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});

// serve static content
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.listen(8080);
```

The above application works just fine, however, I can see that socket.io is no longer using websockets, it is instead falling back to XHR polling.

I can confirm that by looking at the logs from the proxy code:

```
proxying GET request /socket.io/1/?t=1391781619101
proxying GET request /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/f-VVzPcV-7_IKJJtl6VN?t=13917816294
proxying POST request /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/f-VVzPcV-7_IKJJtl6VN?t=1391781629
proxying GET request /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/f-VVzPcV-7_IKJJtl6VN?t=13917816294
proxying GET request /socket.io/1/xhr-polling/f-VVzPcV-7_IKJJtl6VN?t=13917816294
```

Does anyone know how to proxy the web sockets communication? All the examples from `node-http-proxy` assume that you want to proxy all traffic, rather than proxying some and serving others.

Comment: Personally I use nginx both as http server and as proxy. It works very well for websocket proxying (that's the reason I switched from apache).

Comment: @dystroy thanks for the tip - although I was hoping for a node-based solution. This is so that developers can have a local set-up that reflects the live deployment.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just stumbled upon your question, and I see that it is still not answered. Well, in case you are still looking for the solution...
The problem in your code is that `app.listen(8080)` is just syntactic sugar for

```
require('http').createServer(app).listen(8080)
```

while `app` itself is just a handler function, not an instance of httpServer (I personally believe that this feature should be removed from Express to avoid confusion).
Thus, your `app.on('upgrade')` is actually never used. You should instead write

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});
server.listen(8080);
```

Hope, that helps.

Comment: this works perfectly! I've created a gist for a setup of browser-sync and express: https://gist.github.com/timaschew/00ba49d3a39bc3dfbe8f

Answer (score -1):

Do you need both servers? If not you could use the same server for static files and to listen for socket connections:

```
// make the http server
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(), server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io;

// serve static content
server.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

server.listen(8080);

// listen for socket connections
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// socket stuff here
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could use one server - but the whole point is that in production the streaming connection will come from a different server! Thanks for your input :-)