# Node Http Proxy Web Socket Balance

Tags: node.js, web-services, sockets, proxy, node-http-proxy

I need to able to balance websocket on application level. Lets say forward websocket request on the basis of message I received, decode it on proxy and then using that data send to another socket server using some logic.

But I am unable to do this. This is the initial code I wrote and trying to do that. This is the server

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var WebSocket = require('ws');

var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.send('something');
});

var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({target: 'ws://localhost:8080', ws:true});


var server = httpProxy.createServer(function(req, res) {
    //SOME LOGIC HERE TO PARSE WS DATA AND SEND TO WS SERVER
    proxy.ws(req, res, { target: 'ws://localhost:8080'});
}).listen(8014);
```

CLIENT

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var WebSocket = require('ws');


var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8014/');

ws.on('open', function () {  
    ws.send("CLIENT");
});

ws.on('message', function (msg) {  
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629752/using-node-http-proxy-to-proxy-websocket-connections)? Might help you

Comment: @NiCkNewman I can proxy fine but I need to balance on the basis of data received without actually breaking the socket connection.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example. In this case the client connects directly to outer.js which then forwards connections to upstream servers (inner.js).

**outer.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var proxies = {
  foo: new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: {
      host: "foo.com",
      port: 8080
    }
  }),
  bar: new httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: {
      host: "bar.com",
      port: 8080
    }
  })
  // extend this...
};

var findUpstream = function(req){
  // TODO return key for lookup in @proxies
};

var proxyServer = http.createServer(function (req, res){
  var upstream = findUpstream(req);
  proxies[upstream].web(req, res);
});

proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  var upstream = findUpstream(req);
  proxies[upstream].ws(req, socket, head);
});

proxyServer.listen(8014);
```

**inner.js**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 8080 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
    });
    ws.send('something');
});
```

In this example you'll need to fill in the `findUpstream` to return the key such as `foo` or `bar` based on data in the request. It'd also be worth putting some error handling in for when the proper upstream server isn't found, but this should illustrate the general idea.